# WordPress CSS alpha value not showing in internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Within my WordPress site I have a problem with the alpha value of a box created. It shows perfectly fine with all browsers apart from Internet Explorer.

The box shows as a solid object in IE but should need to have an alpha value of around 70% visible. I have tried the `opacity` tribute but hasn't worked for me so far.

```
#category_pg { width:880px; margin:210px auto; }
#catdescription { display:none; position:absolute; top:-8px; right:-2px; font-size: 1.8em; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold; margin:5px; }
#holdme { position:relative; margin-bottom:15px; }
#hideme { position:absolute; top:0px; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:1; padding:6px; margin:-6px 0 0 -9px; opacity:0.7;}
#postbg { position:relative; height:100%; width: 100%; border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; 
border: 3px; border-style:solid;
<?php global $is_IE; if( !$is_IE ) : ?>
background: <?php echo $dmsint_boxrgba; ?>; 
border-left-color: <?php echo $lightborder; ?>; border-bottom-color: <?php echo $darkborder; ?>; border-top-color: <?php echo $lightborder; ?>; border-right-color: <?php echo $darkborder; ?>;
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( $is_IE ) : ?>
background-color:<?php echo $dmsint_boxbg; ?>; zoom:1; 
border-left-color: <?php echo $lightborderie; ?>; border-bottom-color: <?php echo $darkborderie; ?>; border-top-color: <?php echo $lightborderie; ?>; border-right-color: <?php echo $darkborderie; ?>;
<?php endif; ?>
}
```

(Please note that this is a template I bought which I have customised)
I am a beginner to coding so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wich IE version .. check this http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Comment: Older versions of IE need a filter, check http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ for a good snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly: "filter: alpha(opacity=50);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.transparent_class {
```

/* IE 8 */

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* IE 5-7 */

filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Netscape */

-moz-opacity: 0.5;

/* Safari 1.x */

-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Good browsers */

opacity: 0.5;
}